# WP7 Mango RichTextBox support for copy&paste

Tags: richtextbox, copy-paste, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

It seems that the RichTextBox control does not support copy&paste. Is it really so? I created a very simple application that had the control with some text in it and i could not select it. Are there properties that control this or it just does not work?

thanks
--oleg

Comment: Seems like its possible to programatically select stuff in the box using the Selection property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.selection(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not support copy or paste unfortunately. If you want to be able to copy formatted text - allow users to switch the view to a TextBox with plain text.