# How do I allow the user to highlight static text for copying to the clipboard?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a page in my Windows Phone 8 app that displays blocks of text (one to several paragraphs). I want to make this text selectable so the user can highlight and copy.

I was originally using TextBlocks. I switched to RichTextBoxes because, while read-only, I assumed they would allow this behavior, but the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647883/user-selecting-text-in-richtextbox-on-windows-phone-8) says no.

I've seen other apps in the store that allow this, so my question is what control, property or method do I need to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the IsReadOnly and BorderThickness properties for TextBox.This will allow you to have a selectable textblock.
eg.
        TextBox IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0"

Comment: I did manage to figure this out last night. Unfortunately, it also requires a fair bit of editing to the default TextBox template to make it look right, but it works as needed.

Comment: Yes,Apart from these editing in default styles,you can have access to additional TextBox APIs.